# Using SQL like for pattern query

Tags: sql, database, sql-like

I have a PHP function that accepts a parameter called $letter and I want to set the default value of the parameter to a pattern which is "any number or any symbol". How can I do that?

This is my query by the way .

```
select ID from $wpdb->posts where post_title LIKE '".$letter."%
```

I tried posting at wordpress stackexchange and they told me to post it here as this is an SQL/general programming question that specific to wordpress.

Thank you! Replies much appreciated :)

Comment: The default value would be `%`, then ? Or just empty since you already have a `%` in that query.

Comment: Which database are you using? I have added a possible solution for MySQL

Comment: It looks like this code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. That's really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match just numbers or letters (I'm not sure exactly what you mean by symbols) you can use the RLIKE operator in MySQL:

```
SELECT ... WHERE post_title RLIKE '^[A-Za-z0-9]'
```

That means by default `$letter` would be `[A-Za-z0-9]` - this means all letters from a to z (both cases) and numbers from 0-9. If you need specific symbols you can add them to the list (but `-` has to be first or last, since otherwise it has a special meaning of range). The `^` character tells it to be at the beginning of the string. So you will need something like:

```
"select ID from $wpdb->posts where post_title RLIKE '^".$letter."%'"
```

Of course I have to warn you against SQL injection attacks if you build your query like this without sanitizing the input (making sure it doesn't have any `'` (apostrophe) in it.

**Edit**

To match a title that starts with a number just use `[0-9]` - that means it will match one digit from 0 to 9

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, actually that is my problem right now. it matches everything when I want is just any number or any symbol.

Comment: Hello thank very much  you for that! :) how about if I'll just want any number?